# PostgreSQL | How to execute a stored procedure in parallel for n number or records?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which can have more that 10000 records. There is a stored procedure which needs to be executed for the data in each row of the table . This procedure is doing some heavy calculation and each table row data is independent of the calculation on the other row. I want to execute this stored procedure to run for at least 10 records of the tables in parallel, so my execution for 10000 records can be done in faster.
How is this possible in PostgreSQL?
I am looking for something equivalent DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE in oracle.
I am using AWS RDS for PostgreSQL

Comment: There is no built-in equivalent to `dbms_parallel` in Postgres. You could try the [pg_background](https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background) extension

Comment: But for a small table like that I doubt that this will make a difference. Also: if "heavy calculation" is a SELECT query, then Postgres can do parallel execution of the query anyway

Comment: PostgreSQL can use parallel execution. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html Note, that user defined functions are PARALLEL UNSAFE by default, so you'll have to mark it safe to be used in parallel. `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`  defines max workers to be used.